# CouchDB replication issue on WAN

Tags: couchdb, replication

I am trying to implement CouchDB replication over WAN. I can do the same when my source & destination servers are on same network. But it fails when both of them are in different network.

I can do a ping from the CMD as well as I can ping the destination CouchDB through curl from source server. But the replication gets failed.
Do I need to do any additional configuration?

Note: Both the machines have windows server 2012 R2  & CouchDB 2.0 installed

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue. I have to update my CouchDB configuration through default.ini file

[fabric]

request_timeout = infinity

[replicator]

connection_timeout = 7200000

request_timeout = infinity

use_checkpoints = true

checkpoint_interval = 30000